# How listen change height bottom sheet layout android

Tags: android

I have the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--suppress AndroidUnknownAttribute -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_corners"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <com.mobilemedia.tanuki.ui.view.RoundedView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:topLeftCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:topRightCornerRadius="16dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetNavHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_sheet_graph" />
    </com.mobilemedia.tanuki.ui.view.RoundedView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsedView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_indicator"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need to listen to the change in height bottom sheet layout for change the position of elements relative to this height

[image]

The item must always be at a height from bottom sheet despite the fact that he is on another fragment in navHostFragment

How listen change height from bottom sheet?

Answer (score 1):

In common case, you can listen to the bottom sheet slide by using [BottomSheetCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback). Override onSlide method and put your actions inside. This method called when the bottom sheet is being dragged. And you can get all the properties of bottomSheet, including height.

But the better way is to implement custom CoordinatorLayout.Behavior. This works only if your depending views and BottomSheet are the children of the same coordinatorlayout.
Just extend [CoordinatorLayout.Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior) and override [layoutDependsOn](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior#layoutDependsOn(androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout,%20V,%20android.view.View)) and [onDependentViewChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior#onDependentViewChanged(androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout,%20V,%20android.view.View)) methods. CoordinatorLayout was made to solve issues like that.
There are many articles about this on the internet, for [example](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26).
There is also a standard floating action button behavior in the android library.

The third way is to use MotionLayout. But it is a more complex, and it can be difficult to start. So I should not suggest it, because it could be over powerful for this task.